# jQuery, select an element

Tags: jquery, element

I have this html :

```
<div id="para0104" class="entry">
<label for="id0104">d</label>
<div>
<label for="input0104100">
<input id="input0104100" type="radio" name="input0104" value="wxcwxc" />
wxcwxc</label>
<label for="input0104100">
<input id="input0104100" type="radio" name="input0104" value="wc" />
wc</label>
<label for="input0104100">
<input id="input0104100" type="radio" name="input0104" value="az" />
az</label></div>
</div>
```

I am in a loop for each input type radio, so $(this) return to me these inputs.

How can i retrieve the value "d" in `<label for="id0104">d</label>` ?

When i try `$(this).parent().parent();` i retrieve `<div>`,
and when i try `$(this).parent().parent().parent();` i retrieve `<div id="para0104" class="entry">`

thanks :)

Comment: Let's the answer battle begin ! may the better win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery closest and select the label child:

```
var txt = $(this).closest('div.entry').children('label').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [closest method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

$(this).closest('div.entry').find('label:first').text()

Comment: No, with this i retrieve wxcwxc, wc and az, not "d"